# How can I execute WinRAR serially against each archive in a folder?

Tags: windows, powershell, archiving, winrar

I have about 100 *large* RAR files in the same folder, and I'm trying to delete a particular filespec from within each archive. I'm using PowerShell 2.0 on Windows Storage Server 2008 R2.

I'm by no means a PowerShell user, here's what I came up with so far:

```
$files=get-childitem .
foreach($filename in $files) { 
  & 'C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe' D $filename *-old.bak
}
```

I *think* something like this will do the trick, but it is spawning *simultaneous* copies of WinRAR, which basically hangs everything up.

How can I tell PowerShell (or WinRAR) to wait until one file's processing is complete before moving to the next one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Start-Process` Commandlet with the `-Wait` option enabled. You might have to shove in your parameters through the `-ArgumentList` Option for them to work.